# Multi boot option for WDS

Tags: windows, linux, multi-boot

I have a Windows Deployment Server (Server 2008 R2) that I use to roll out XP/Vista/7 installs using the standard retail CDs.

I am looking to expand its functionality to include DOS/Linux/Repair Utilities and OEM versions of Windows such as the XPA 32 in 1 Multiboot DVD for machines that will not boot from USB/Physical CD (ancient machines)

I have not been able to find a solution that works correctly with WDS.

Does anyone have experience with this?

Answer (score 0):

With a little Linux hackery you can make this work through your WDS server. Take a look at [WDSLINUX](http://www.syslinux.org/wiki/index.php/WDSLINUX). What you'll end up doing is booting to PXELINUX and then booting to your Windows installs, repair utilities, etc.

About a year ago I tried to garner interest in a project like this for a college course. It had lofty goals and I ended up being the only one interested, but you might be able to glean *some* useful information from the [wiki](http://trollfacepxe.wikidot.com/start) I started for it, particularly the [log](http://trollfacepxe.wikidot.com/log) I had going has links to any problems I encountered while setting it up.

Comment: Thanks Tanner I tried a smilar method before but ran into issues with x64 versions of Windows. I even had parted magic booting the same as you!

Answer (score 0):

If you have a WDS server, and you want a repair boot option, look into MSDART.

It will build wim files (which work flawlessly with WDS) that you boot to across the network, and put even the best Linux freebie repair disks to shame.

[image]

MORE INFO: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/jj190826